# Dropbox Signature issues when downloading file, but account/info works fine

Tags: api, rest, dropbox

Dropbox Signature issues when downloading file, but account/info works fine:

This - 
https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info?oauth_consumer_key=cy6ymyqsb2yymw1&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_token=e98gtg5b2wo9o51&oauth_signature=o2jwldqtqfbmqkg%2526ller5vort89ab2r

works perfect all the time.

This - 
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/test.txt?oauth_consumer_key=cy6ymyqsb2yymw1&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_token=e98gtg5b2wo9o51&oauth_signature=o2jwldqtqfbmqkg%2526ller5vort89ab2r

Produces an error:

403 Forbidden,
{"error": "Host: rpc.dropbox.com:443, FE: None, X-Dropbox-RequestId: None, Bad oauth_signature for oauth_signature_method 'PLAINTEXT'"}

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue.

In request

https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/test.txt?oauth_consumer_key=cy6ymyqsb2yymw1&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_token=e98gtg5b2wo9o51&oauth_signature=o2jwldqtqfbmqkg%2526ller5vort89ab2r

%2526 is double escaped &. Fixing this helped.

But interesting that first query has the same issue, but Drobpox doesn't complain.