# Dropbox PLAINTEXT REST API on AppEngine DownloadError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, dropbox-api

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. I've made a little dropbox API app which:

1. Gets the list of /Photos using the /diff API
2. Fetches each photo
3. Parses the EXIF data
4. Stores the EXIF data back into appengine.

I wrote it up and it works great on dev_appserver, but it fails when deployed to appengine.

**The calls to the /delta work correctly, but calls to /files fail with an opaque "DownloadError".**

Anyways, here is the relevant chunk of code:

```
def fetch_image(self, path):
  url = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox' + path
  try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(
      url=url,
      method=urlfetch.GET,
      allow_truncated=True,
      headers={ 'Authorization': get_authorization_header(self.authorization) })
  except DownloadError, exception:
    logging.exception(exception)
    logging.debug(get_authorization_header(self.authorization))

def get_delta(self, cursor=None):
  url = 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta'
  params = {
    'path_prefix': '/Photos',
  }
  if cursor is not None:
    params['cursor'] = cursor
  result = urlfetch.fetch(
    url=url,
    method=urlfetch.POST,
    payload=urllib.urlencode(params),
    headers={ 'Authorization': get_authorization_header(self.authorization) })
  return json.loads(result.content)
```

get_authorization_header produces the output like:

```
OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="<app-key>", oauth_token="<access-token>", oauth_signature="<app-secret>&<access-token-secret>"
```

An example stack trace shows that there doesn't appear to be any error_detail.

```
Unable to fetch URL: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Photos/**redacted**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/**redacted**", line 295, in update_image
    headers={ 'Authorization': getAuthorizationHeader(self.authorization) })
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 416, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError("Unable to fetch URL: " + url + error_detail)
DownloadError: Unable to fetch URL: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Photos/**redacted**
```

I vaguely suspect this might be related to appengine mangling the authorization header into something like what happened in [question 14716545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716545/dropbox-signature-issues-when-downloading-file-but-account-info-works-fine) since it works on api and not on api-content, but I haven't been able to set up a test for that yet. Even if it is the case, there isn't anything I can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have it figured out. Basically I wasn't encoding the request url correctly. I was getting something like:

https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Photos/Some Event/Some File Name.jpg

which fails, but:

https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Photos/Some%20Event/Some%20File%20Name.jpg

works!